# わけ、の、理由 in explanations.... when do you use which one?

Tags: grammar, word-choice

These all seem to be used for explanation... when do you use one over the other? Could you offer some examples?

To clarify about の, I am talking about its use in providing information, like,  昨日、デパートに行ったんです

Comment: I am pretty sure you have seen some examples where these words are used for explanation.  (Otherwise why would they _seem_ to be used in that way in the first place?)  Please include examples in the question.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question by using more words?  By の, are you referring to the の in phrases such as のです and のである?  If so, I do not understand why it is grouped with わけ and 理由, which are nouns.

Comment: @Tokyo Nagoya: I have some idea on why OP grouped の with わけ and 理由, but I’d rather wait for OP to edit the question than editing it by myself.

Comment: I can understand the grouping of の・わけ and わけ・理由 but not the grouping of all three...

Comment: My idea on why OP grouped の with わけ and 理由 was wrong, and I am glad that I did not edit the question. :)

Comment: I still do not understand what OP wants to find out.  I feel like what he is trying to ask is a very good question, though.  He definitely needs to use more words.  More specific the questions, the better answers he will get.

Comment: あなたが船を選んだ_の_は、私への思いやりだったのでしょうか？(「海岸通り」から)...かな？